# Is it possible to have one view for two action in asp.net mvc3 razor view?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, timezone

I need to add time zone in view.

```
dynamic viewData = new ExpandoObject();
            viewData.TimeZones = from p in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
                                 select new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                     Text = p.DisplayName,
                                     Value = p.Id
                                 };
```

How can I send "viewData" to view. I have done it in different action, but cannot do this in same action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ViewBag`:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.TimeZones = 
        from p in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = p.DisplayName,
            Value = p.Id
        };
    return View();
}
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "SelectedTimeZone", 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.TimeZones
)
```

Comment: Darin has give you the answer you can put your timezone in viewbag in your action or as many you want and call it in view in paragraph or div